# Do we need _strict_ monotonicity for the fixed point lemma for normal functions?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, fixed-point-theorems

I was reading about the [fixed-point lemma for normal functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_lemma_for_normal_functions) and I was wondering if we could weaken strict monotonicity to non-decreasing. I see why it's necessary for the proof, but is there a continuous *non-decreasing* ordinal operation without a fixed point? I'm probably missing something obvious but I can't think of any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need that $f$ is strictly increasing to have at least one fixed point. Consider the sequence $\alpha_n = f^n(0)$. By induction it follows that this is non-decreasing. If $\alpha_n=\alpha_{n+1} $ for some $n$ then we are done as this means that $\alpha_n = f(\alpha_n)$. Else consider the sup of this sequence and follow by continuity that this is a fixed point.

Of course you cannot get arbitrarily large fixed points as witnessed by the constant $0$ function.

Answer (score -1):

With $\ell(\alpha)=\min\{\,\lambda\mid \lambda\text{ is limit ordinal}, \lambda>\alpha\,\}$, let
$$ f(\alpha)=\begin{cases}\ell(\alpha)&\text{if }\alpha\text{ is limit ordinal}&\\\ell(\ell(\alpha))&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Then $f$ is continuous, non-decreasing, and has no fixed point.

Comment: Why is this continuous? It looks discontinuous at $\omega\cdot\omega$, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Jonathan: It actually seems discontinuous at every limit ordinal, for example every finite $\alpha$ gives $f(\alpha)=\omega$, but $f(\omega)=\omega+\omega$.

Comment: @Asaf finite successors $\alpha$ give $\omega +\omega$, the next next limit.

Comment: @Jonathan: Ah, you're right. I misread. Thanks.